# How to get Count of records Group By field value in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, group-by, mongodb-query

I want to get total count of records by group field (country) value, I am trying but not getting the it. Here is my code below:-

```
var company_id= company._id
 FollowCompany.aggregate(
      [   
          {
            $match: { company_id :company_id }  // company_id field in database and user param
          },
          {
              $group:
              {
                  _id: "$country" ,   // need to group by country in database
                  count: { $sum:1 },

              }
          },
          { $sort : { entry_date : -1 } },
      ]).exec(function(err, followerData) {
        console.log(followerData)

      })
```

Its shows empty result, any help or idea ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using mongoose ? What is the type of the `company_id`? string or objectID

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet, its id stored in database and getting the same from user input

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet, yes and I edit the code as well

Comment: Convert it to ObjectId. `{
            $match: { company_id :mongoose.Types.ObjectId(company_id) } 
          }`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet, while working with $match its working fine, its giving me the result, I want to group that data by a field, country.

Comment: Could you show some sample documents

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet, yes....

Comment: {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "xxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "company_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "user_id": "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "country": "India",
    "entry_date": {
        "$date": "2018-12-10T02:33:16.846Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
}

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet, please read the answer

Comment: you should add entry_date  in your $group

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, now I want to show _id field as country, any solution, here is my code below:

```
 FollowCompany.aggregate(
      [   
          {
            $match: {company_id:""+company_id+""}
          },
          {
              $group:
              {
                  _id: "$country" , 
                  count: { $sum:1 },

              }
          },
          { $sort : { _id : 1 } },
      ])
```

and output is

```
 {
        "_id": "India",
        "count": 1
    }
```

I want like this

```
 {
        "country": "India",
        "count": 1
    }
```

Comment: Use `$project` stage at the end. Something like `{ "$project": { "country": "$_id", "count": 1, "_id": 0  }}`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet, Thanks alot, it works, as I pass company_id as string, is there another way to convert this string ?